How to target .Mui-selected state class using CSS modules
I would like to customize the selected tab of the MUI Tabs component. My styling choice is CSS modules. But I have difficulties applying the correct selector. I have also applied their CSS injection order so that I can customize the styles according to the docs.
I tried the following according to their documentation.
I have a class for my custom tab called .myTab.
.myTab.Mui-selected {
 color: red;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

then I apply the class to my Tab.

    <Tab
      className={classes.myTab}>
      {children}
    </Tab>


But I have no success so far.

You need to use :global() selector of CSS Modules like this:
.myTab:global(.Mui-selected) {
  color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.
